# Update Certificate of KeyStore file

Tags: android, android-keystore, jks

I have an application which has had a keystore file for a very long time. I have shared it with my colleagues for signing the live apk before publishing updates. Now, they do not work with me anymore, but my keystore remains the same. How do i prevent them from sending an update to my application,considering the fact that they have my application code as well as login credentials to my play store account?

Comment: Change your login credentials to prevent them.